# Validate input of scanf

Tags: c

I need to read hours:minutes in this exact format. I use:

```
    int hours, minutes;

    if (scanf("%d:%d", &hours, &minutes)!= 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
else if (minutes>60 || minutes<0 || hours<0)
    {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    time = hours*60 + minutes;

    /*read another time interval */
     if (scanf("%d:%d", &hours, &minutes)!= 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong input 2.\n");
        return 1;
    }
else if (minutes>60 || minutes<0 || hours<0)
    {
        printf("Wrong input 2.\n");
        return 1;
    }
   ...
```

works fine, but I need to get "wrong input" also in situations that someone enters e.g. 5:38abc

Comment: you need to see if type(minutes) or type(hours) is not `int`. Can you put your declarations for hours and minutes in the code snippet? If you have declared your `hours` and `minutes` in `int`, anything other than pure `int` will be incorrect anyway!

Comment: I have declared them as int. Problem is that the "abc" at the end  does not cause error in this scanf, but later in the code on the next scanf which also reads int.

Comment: could you please put more code in the snippet cause telling us what you have done in comments doesn't really paint a good picture!

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious what his issue is. `scanf` stops reading as soon as it gets something that doesn't match the template. The excess doesn't cause it to report an error like he wants.

Comment: In other words, the time must be immediately followed by a newline?

Comment: the input is should be entered like 20:09(PRESS ENTER). If the scanf statement is like this `scanf("%2d:%2d", &hours, &minutes)`, any strings/characters entered like 20:09abc will be ignored as it reads a 2-digit integer, a colon separator, and (only) another 2-digit integer. In this way, errors are prevented. Also typeof can be used to check if anything is not a certain type.

Comment: Barmar is correct. I need to report an error if there is anythig else between 3:50..... and the newline

Comment: The input `5:38abc` will cause your code to print '`Wrong input 2.`' -- is there something else it should do?  If you need to differentiate between newlines and other whitespace, scanf is probably not the right choice, as it treats them the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an operator to the format string to match the newline:

```
int hours, minutes;
char str[2];

if (scanf("%d:%d%1[\n]", &hours, &minutes, str)!= 3)
```

`%[\n]` matches newline characters, and the field width `1` makes it stop matching after exactly 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is to read an entire line using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) (so the line is in a buffer), then to parse that line. You could use [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) - perhaps with its `%n` specifier - or you could parse that line more manually with e.g. [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) (which sets the end pointer).

So something like:

```
int endpos= -1;
char linbuf[32];
memset(linbuf, 0, sizeof(linbuf));
if (!fgets(linbuf, sizeof(linbuf)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (sscanf(linbuf, "%O2d:%02d%n", &hour, &minute, &endpos)<2)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (endpos!=6) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (hour<0 || minute<0 || hour>=24 || minute>=60) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Of course you would replace the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` with a more user-friendly rejection.

BTW, you should specify if `1:2` is acceptable input or if you require `01:02`. And would you accept an empty line as representing noon?